# Trying to replicate encryption of an android app

Tags: android, encryption, obfuscation, patch-reversing, javascript

I was trying to replicate/copy the encryption of an android app which uses CryptoJS with sha256 encryption as having seen in the source code of the android app. fingerprinting the app, it was built with reactJS and TypeScript and apparently compiled with Babel compiler, which all I don't understand them thoroughly.
the code encrypts a signature to communicate with the server, Here is a snippet of the code:

```
f = t.type + "&" + encodeURIComponent(t.url) + "&" + n + "&" + u + "&" + b + 
                                "&LS8goCQy4O2w5xnPmEOp/PjtKe37+d9HxRthqug9VC0=",
Signature = hexToBase64((0, c.default)(f).toString());
```

in the snippet code `Signature = hexToBase64((0, c.default)(f).toString());` the **signature** is calculated but unfortunately because of source code was uglified and minified, in my research I identified the code responsible to calculate the signature is as follows:

```
__d(function (g, r, i, a, m, e, d) {
        var t,
        n;
        t = this,
        n = function (t) {
            return (function (n) {
                var o = t,
                s = o.lib,
                c = s.WordArray,
                f = s.Hasher,
                h = o.algo,
                u = [],
                l = [];
                !(function () {
                    function t(t) {
                        for (var o = n.sqrt(t), s = 2; s <= o; s++)
                            if (!(t % s))
                                return !1;
                        return !0
                    }
                    function o(t) {
                        return 4294967296 * (t - (0 | t)) | 0
                    }
                    for (var s = 2, c = 0; c < 64; )
                        t(s) && (c < 8 && (u[c] = o(n.pow(s, .5))), l[c] = o(n.pow(s, .3333333333333333)), c++), s++
                })();
                var _ = [],
                v = h.SHA256 = f.extend({
                    _doReset: function () {
                        this._hash = new c.init(u.slice(0))
                    },
                    _doProcessBlock: function (t, n) {
                        for (var o = this._hash.words, s = o[0], c = o[1], f = o[2], h = o[3], u = o[4], v = o[5], p = o[6], H = o[7], y = 0; y < 64; y++) {
                            if (y < 16)
                                _[y] = 0 | t[n + y];
                            else {
                                var w = _[y - 15],
                                A = (w << 25 | w >>> 7) ^ (w << 14 | w >>> 18) ^ w >>> 3,
                                S = _[y - 2],
                                B = (S << 15 | S >>> 17) ^ (S << 13 | S >>> 19) ^ S >>> 10;
                                _[y] = A + _[y - 7] + B + _[y - 16]
                            }
                            var b = s & c ^ s & f ^ c & f,
                            x = (s << 30 | s >>> 2) ^ (s << 19 | s >>> 13) ^ (s << 10 | s >>> 22),
                            j = H + ((u << 26 | u >>> 6) ^ (u << 21 | u >>> 11) ^ (u << 7 | u >>> 25)) + (u & v ^ ~u & p) + l[y] + _[y];
                            H = p,
                            p = v,
                            v = u,
                            u = h + j | 0,
                            h = f,
                            f = c,
                            c = s,
                            s = j + (x + b) | 0
                        }
                        o[0] = o[0] + s | 0,
                        o[1] = o[1] + c | 0,
                        o[2] = o[2] + f | 0,
                        o[3] = o[3] + h | 0,
                        o[4] = o[4] + u | 0,
                        o[5] = o[5] + v | 0,
                        o[6] = o[6] + p | 0,
                        o[7] = o[7] + H | 0
                    },
                    _doFinalize: function () {
                        var t = this._data,
                        o = t.words,
                        s = 8 * this._nDataBytes,
                        c = 8 * t.sigBytes;
                        return o[c >>> 5] |= 128 << 24 - c % 32,
                        o[14 + (c + 64 >>> 9 << 4)] = n.floor(s / 4294967296),
                        o[15 + (c + 64 >>> 9 << 4)] = s,
                        t.sigBytes = 4 * o.length,
                        this._process(),
                        this._hash
                    },
                    clone: function () {
                        var t = f.clone.call(this);
                        return t._hash = this._hash.clone(),
                        t
                    }
                });
                o.SHA256 = f._createHelper(v),
                o.HmacSHA256 = f._createHmacHelper(v)
            })(Math),
            t.SHA256
        },
        "object" == typeof e ? m.exports = e = n(r(d[0])) : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["./core"], n) : n(t.CryptoJS)
    }, 725, [726]);
```

another method with same functionality but with some minor changes was also defined:

```
    __d(function (g, r, i, a, m, e, d) {
        var t,
        n;
        t = this,
        n = function () {
            var t = t || (function (t, n) {
                var o = Object.create || (function () {
                    function t() {}
                    return function (n) {
                        var o;
                        return t.prototype = n,
                        o = new t,
                        t.prototype = null,
                        o
                    }
                })(),
                s = {},
                c = s.lib = {},
                u = c.Base = {
                    extend: function (t) {
                        var n = o(this);
                        return t && n.mixIn(t),
                        n.hasOwnProperty('init') && this.init !== n.init || (n.init = function () {
                            n.$super.init.apply(this, arguments)
                        }),
                        n.init.prototype = n,
                        n.$super = this,
                        n
                    },
                    create: function () {
                        var t = this.extend();
                        return t.init.apply(t, arguments),
                        t
                    },
                    init: function () {},
                    mixIn: function (t) {
                        for (var n in t)
                            t.hasOwnProperty(n) && (this[n] = t[n]);
                        t.hasOwnProperty('toString') && (this.toString = t.toString)
                    },
                    clone: function () {
                        return this.init.prototype.extend(this)
                    }
                },
                f = c.WordArray = u.extend({
                    init: function (t, n) {
                        t = this.words = t || [],
                        this.sigBytes = void 0 != n ? n : 4 * t.length
                    },
                    toString: function (t) {
                        return (t || p).stringify(this)
                    },
                    concat: function (t) {
                        var n = this.words,
                        o = t.words,
                        s = this.sigBytes,
                        c = t.sigBytes;
                        if (this.clamp(), s % 4)
                            for (var u = 0; u < c; u++) {
                                var f = o[u >>> 2] >>> 24 - u % 4 * 8 & 255;
                                n[s + u >>> 2] |= f << 24 - (s + u) % 4 * 8
                            }
                        else
                            for (u = 0; u < c; u += 4)
                                n[s + u >>> 2] = o[u >>> 2];
                        return this.sigBytes += c,
                        this
                    },
                    clamp: function () {
                        var n = this.words,
                        o = this.sigBytes;
                        n[o >>> 2] &= 4294967295 << 32 - o % 4 * 8,
                        n.length = t.ceil(o / 4)
                    },
                    clone: function () {
                        var t = u.clone.call(this);
                        return t.words = this.words.slice(0),
                        t
                    },
                    random: function (n) {
                        for (var o, s = [], c = function (n) {
                            n = n;
                            var o = 987654321,
                            s = 4294967295;
                            return function () {
                                var c = ((o = 36969 * (65535 & o) + (o >> 16) & s) << 16) + (n = 18e3 * (65535 & n) + (n >> 16) & s) & s;
                                return c /= 4294967296,
                                (c += .5) * (t.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1)
                            }
                        }, u = 0; u < n; u += 4) {
                            var h = c(4294967296 * (o || t.random()));
                            o = 987654071 * h(),
                            s.push(4294967296 * h() | 0)
                        }
                        return new f.init(s, n)
                    }
                }),
                h = s.enc = {},
                p = h.Hex = {
                    stringify: function (t) {
                        for (var n = t.words, o = t.sigBytes, s = [], c = 0; c < o; c++) {
                            var u = n[c >>> 2] >>> 24 - c % 4 * 8 & 255;
                            s.push((u >>> 4).toString(16)),
                            s.push((15 & u).toString(16))
                        }
                        return s.join('')
                    },
                    parse: function (t) {
                        for (var n = t.length, o = [], s = 0; s < n; s += 2)
                            o[s >>> 3] |= parseInt(t.substr(s, 2), 16) << 24 - s % 8 * 4;
                        return new f.init(o, n / 2)
                    }
                },
                l = h.Latin1 = {
                    stringify: function (t) {
                        for (var n = t.words, o = t.sigBytes, s = [], c = 0; c < o; c++) {
                            var u = n[c >>> 2] >>> 24 - c % 4 * 8 & 255;
                            s.push(String.fromCharCode(u))
                        }
                        return s.join('')
                    },
                    parse: function (t) {
                        for (var n = t.length, o = [], s = 0; s < n; s++)
                            o[s >>> 2] |= (255 & t.charCodeAt(s)) << 24 - s % 4 * 8;
                        return new f.init(o, n)
                    }
                },
                y = h.Utf8 = {
                    stringify: function (t) {
                        try {
                            return decodeURIComponent(escape(l.stringify(t)))
                        } catch (t) {
                            throw new Error('Malformed UTF-8 data')
                        }
                    },
                    parse: function (t) {
                        return l.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(t)))
                    }
                },
                v = c.BufferedBlockAlgorithm = u.extend({
                    reset: function () {
                        this._data = new f.init,
                        this._nDataBytes = 0
                    },
                    _append: function (t) {
                        'string' == typeof t && (t = y.parse(t)),
                        this._data.concat(t),
                        this._nDataBytes += t.sigBytes
                    },
                    _process: function (n) {
                        var o = this._data,
                        s = o.words,
                        c = o.sigBytes,
                        u = this.blockSize,
                        h = c / (4 * u),
                        p = (h = n ? t.ceil(h) : t.max((0 | h) - this._minBufferSize, 0)) * u,
                        l = t.min(4 * p, c);
                        if (p) {
                            for (var y = 0; y < p; y += u)
                                this._doProcessBlock(s, y);
                            var v = s.splice(0, p);
                            o.sigBytes -= l
                        }
                        return new f.init(v, l)
                    },
                    clone: function () {
                        var t = u.clone.call(this);
                        return t._data = this._data.clone(),
                        t
                    },
                    _minBufferSize: 0
                }),
                w = (c.Hasher = v.extend({
                        cfg: u.extend(),
                        init: function (t) {
                            this.cfg = this.cfg.extend(t),
                            this.reset()
                        },
                        reset: function () {
                            v.reset.call(this),
                            this._doReset()
                        },
                        update: function (t) {
                            return this._append(t),
                            this._process(),
                            this
                        },
                        finalize: function (t) {
                            return t && this._append(t),
                            this._doFinalize()
                        },
                        blockSize: 16,
                        _createHelper: function (t) {
                            return function (n, o) {
                                return new t.init(o).finalize(n)
                            }
                        },
                        _createHmacHelper: function (t) {
                            return function (n, o) {
                                return new w.HMAC.init(t, o).finalize(n)
                            }
                        }
                    }), s.algo = {});
                return s
            })(Math);
            return t
        },
        "object" == typeof e ? m.exports = e = n() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], n) : t.CryptoJS = n()
    }, 726, []);
```

I didn't really understand which one is responsible to reproduce a signature like this : `aoRxyvXwpTMh5wzMSz3nGZkkHwo6spNL1cz6qwjvnBA=`

additionally in my research I was able to produce a signature but the server always returns invalid signature:

```
app signature : aoRxyvXwpTMh5wzMSz3nGZkkHwo6spNL1cz6qwjvnBA=

signature produced : Xpw28zTUMeJE9x4ki73tTs55IxDQy5Y4d0p9kgQgfo8=
```

what am I missing from the above code snippet? can I change it into a pure javascript code?